# Is $\frac{1}{1+0.1x}$ hyperbolic in $x$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

I understand that hyperbolic functions are related to trigonometric functions. However, I often see it used in other contexts. For example, this function is described to be hyperbolic

$$\frac{1}{1+0.1x},$$

in some textbook on discounting. Is this true? I can tell that the derivative is strictly increasing (i.e. becoming less negative) in $x$. But surely this isn't sufficient.

Comment: The function describes a hyperbola in the cartesian plane (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Hyperbola_with_equation_y=A/x) for example), but I don't recall having heard it called "*hyperbolic*", and that would sound quite odd, indeed.

Comment: There are terms for Mobius transformations, which this is. However, since you say the textbook is about "discounting" one must wonder

Comment: @WillJagy See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_discounting#Formal_model